# Active verbs with passive meanings

Tags: grammar-identification, passive-voice, irregular-words

Every beginning Latin-learner is familiar with the idea of deponent verbs: verbs that have passive forms but active meanings.

I am curious about a small subset of Latin verbs that aren't just *intransitive*, but have unmistakably *passive meanings*. I can think of two important examples now, though I am sure there are more:

- [**vapulo, -are, -avi, -atus**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvapulo): to be beaten
- [**v(a)eneo, -ire, -ivi, -itum**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=veneo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059): to be sold

(Actually, the second example appears to be easily explicable: *vaeneo* = *venum eo*: to go to sale)

A few clarifications:

1. **Are these verbs really distinctive** at all? Would they have struck a Roman as being passive, or is this just a case where we lack an English translation that is not passive? A remark from a (post-)classical grammarian regarding *vapulare* would be helpful here.
2. Assuming they are *sui generis*, **what are some other verbs (if any) that belong to this category**?
3. Are there any **distinctive grammatical features** of verbs like this? For instance, could "I am beaten by him" be translated *vapulo ab eo*?

Comment: The second conjugation *iacēre* is kind of a passive of the third conjugation *iacĕre*. It's more like "to be in a thrown state, to have been thrown" than "to be thrown". Would you count this as a passive meaning? Second conjugation verbs seem to describe states rather than actions.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That might work, though I guess "lie" is a pretty good English translation in most cases. Your remark about the 2nd conjugation is interesting--I remember noticing the same thing about French (*blanchir*, *rougir*, *blêmir*). It's not universal, though: we certainly have verbs like *moneo* and *video* that are transitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In linguistic parlance these verbs are usually called “stative”, not “passive”. From a Latin standpoint they differ from passive verbs in that they cannot (apparently) be construed with an agent (Latin ab + ablative).

Ancient Indo-European is believed to have had an active and a middle voice, but no passive. But it did have the facility to form stative stems using the suffix *-yo-. In Sanskrit these verbs are conjugated with middle-voice endings, but in Latin they take active endings. iacere vs. iacēre is a classic example.

Comment: I just found an interesting quote from Quintilian: (*Inst. Orat.* 9.2.12.3-4: "...tum augendi criminis gratia, ut testis in reum, rogatus an **ab reo fustibus uapulasset**, 'innocens', inquit..."

Comment: Interresting...

Answer (score 4):

I think the notion of "passive meaning" is quite elusive. Nevertheless, if neuter nouns can be the subject of intransitive verbs (like *quid si nunc caelum ruat*), which makes them, in my opinion, susceptible of having "a passive meaning" in actuality: reality-base view, why couldn't them, at least theoretically, receive the ablative of agent?

L&S in [*cado*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=cado&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) suggests it can be coupled with ablative of agent with or without preposition(*):

> torqueor, infesto ne vir **ab hoste cadat** (Lest my man will fall by the aggressive enemy)

> barbarae postquam **cecidere** turmae **Thessalo victore** (troops fell by Thessalus)

(*) As Mitomono notes, *Thessalo victore* is understood by [some commentators](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0024%3Abook%3D2%3Apoem%3D4) as an ablative absolute.

According to [A&G](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-agent):

> The Ablative of the Agent with ab is sometimes used after intransitive verbs that have a passive sense. **perīre ab hoste** (to be slain by an enemy)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that your second example is from Horace (NB: in prose the proper/so-called "ablative of the agent" _without_ a preposition is not (usually) admissible). In fact, it is not obvious (at least to me) that _Thessalo victore_ must be analyzed here as a proper "ablative of agent". According to some commentators, it is an "ablative absolute": e.g., cf. the section of "notes" on the right of http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0024%3Abook%3D2%3Apoem%3D4

Comment: Those examples of "intransitive verbs that have a passive sense" (e.g. _cado_, _pereo_, etc.) can be claimed to coincide with (a subset of) the ones that involve a Theme/Patient subject (rather than an Agent subject). In the linguistic literature they are often referred to as "unaccusative verbs": cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb