# Is there something like an "anti-deponent" verb in Latin?

Tags: verbs, deponent-verbs

[Deponent verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deponent_verb) are those who are written (normally) in passive form but are active in meaning. [loquor, loquī, locūtus sum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loquor#Latin) is a common example in Latin. I wonder if the opposite exists, i.e. a verb which is active in form but passive in meaning. To be honest, I cannot even think of one in Spanish or English, which might indicate that this does not exist in Latin either. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/active-verbs-with-passive-meanings

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that *iacēre* is of this kind.
Morphologically it is fully active, but semantically it can be seen as a passive form of *iacĕre*.
[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=jaceo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) describe it as "to be thrown" and hence "to lie".
However, *iacēre* is not syntactically fully passive:
It is intransitive so it takes no objects, but to my knowledge it cannot take an agent.

There may well be more verbs like this, but the pair *iacere/iacere* is the most common one I know.
Many verbs of the second conjugation describe a state rather than an action, which is well compatible with the *-ē-* working as a passive indicator here.

Comment: Interesting. Now I might finally be able to remember which is _iacēre_ and which is _iacĕre_!

Answer (score 4):

These are the textbook examples:

- *Fio* (and its compounds) functions as the passive of *facio* (and its compounds). It even can take an agent. But it has some passive forms (*fieri*, *factus sum*).
- *Veneo* functions as the passive of *vendo*.

Comment: Those are good ones! Do you know if *veneo* can take an agent? Or are there other signs that it functions syntactically, not just semantically, as a passive of *vendo*?

Comment: I don't know, I have never seen it but have little experience with texts with this verb. Ablative without preposition, at any rate, is that of price, not agent, here.

Answer (score 4):

Another common example that comes to mind is [*vapulo, -are*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvapulo), which means "to be beaten."

In at least one case cited in L&S from Quintilian's *Institutio Oratoria*, *vapulo* can even be paired with an ablative of agent:

> . . . testis in reum, rogatus an **ab reo fustibus uapulasset**, 'innocens', inquit. . . .